# Decrementing a time in python

Tags: python

I have a timer in a game I'm programming in python/pygame.

The timer works fine when I have everything in the main class:

```
time=50

seconds_passed = clock.tick()/1000.0
time-=seconds
draw_time=math.tranc(time)
print(draw_time)
```

However when I move this into a new class player

```
class player():
   .
   .
   .
   set_time(self, draw_time):
        seconds_passed = clock.tick()/1000.0
        time-=seconds_passed
        draw_time=math.tranc(time)
        print(draw_time)
```

When I call this function in the main class:

```
class main():
    . 
    .
    .
    draw_time=20
    player = Player()
    print player.set_time(draw_time)
```

My time is not decrementing however stays the same!

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can functions in Python print variables in enclosing scope but cannot use them in assignment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864041/why-can-functions-in-python-print-variables-in-enclosing-scope-but-cannot-use-th)

Comment: What is `seconds` and what is its relationship to `seconds_passed`?

Comment: sorry typo, fixed -edit

Comment: Classes should begin with uppercase, and you don't need the parens, e.g. 'class Main:`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you are decrementing `time` in your method, you are only modifying a copy of the value.  To be able to modify it you can pass a reference to an object instead.  You can use for example a [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

```
from datetime import timedelta

class player():
   set_time(self, draw_time):
        seconds_passed = clock.tick()/1000.0
        time -= timedelta(seconds=seconds_passed)
        draw_time=math.tranc(time.seconds)
        print(draw_time)

class main():
    draw_time = timedelta(seconds=20)
    player = Player()
    print player.set_time(draw_time)
```

Comment: sorry, i dont want a time, i meant a timer which decrements

Comment: Sure, you can create yourself a Timer class instead which you can use for keeping track of time. The timedelta was just one way of solving it.