# Python: modify method-local variable inside inner method

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, global, python-nonlocal

I'm writing a test method called, say, `test_foo` (using pytest). I am testing the behavior of a function, `foo`, which takes as an argument another function, `get`. `foo` calls `get` iteratively, conditionally on the return value of `get`, e.g.:

```
def foo(get, param):
    max_num_tries = 3
    curr_num_tries = 0
    response = get(param)
    while curr_num_tries < max_num_tries and response.status_code == BAD_STATUS_CODE:
        response = get(param)
    return response
```

I am trying to override `get` such that it has access to how many times it's been called and can return different values accordingly.

Here's a simplified version of what I have so far:

```
def test_foo():
    tries_so_far = 0

    def get(arg1):
        global tries_so_far
        if tries_so_far < 3:
            tries_so_far += 1
            print("do something special here")
        else:
            print("do something else here")
        return "some return val"

    foo(get, "some arg")
```

However, I get the following error:

`NameError: global name 'tries_so_far' is not defined`

If I define `tries_so_far` outside of `test_foo`, at the module level, I get the expected behavior. However, I would like `tries_so_far` to be a variable that is local to `test_foo`.

Is there some way to give `get` read/write to `tries_so_far` using globals, or some other technique? Note: I cannot change the parameters or return value of `get`.

Comment: You do not appear to be using write access to `tries_so_far`. Just remove the `global` and it will be able to read the variable. `global` means "module level", as you have correctly determined.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to add that into my example. Updated.

Comment: I am assuming you are using Py3k from the print statements. If that is true, can you change the tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to modify variable in python that is in outer, but not global, scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447947/is-it-possible-to-modify-variable-in-python-that-is-in-outer-but-not-global-sc) and [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the accepted answer for this question [Why can functions in Python print variables in enclosing scope but cannot use them in assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864041/why-can-functions-in-python-print-variables-in-enclosing-scope-but-cannot-use-th), there is an additional statement added in Python 3: `nonlocal` that does what you want. It is like `global`, but says to look at the enclosing scope instead of the module level. The following modification should therefore allow you to do exactly what you want:

```
def test_foo():
    tries_so_far = 0

    def get(arg1):
        nonlocal tries_so_far
        if tries_so_far < 3:
            tries_so_far += 1
            print("do something special here")
        else:
            print("do something else here")
        return "some return val"

    foo(get, "some arg")
```

While your question is not an exact duplicate of the one I cited above, you should read the accepted answer. It is very good and will probably address many unstated questions that you have on the subject.