# Unresolved reference in a python local function

Tags: python-3.x, scope, namespaces

Usually in a local function I should be able to access any variable declared in enclosing scope. But I'm getting Unresolved reference error. Here is the code snippet.

```
import time
def make_timer():
    last_called = None
    def elapsed():
        now = time.time()
        print(last_called)
        # nonlocal last_called
        if last_called is None:
            last_called = now
        return None
        elapsed_time = now - last_called
        last_called = now
        return elapsed_time
    return elapsed
```

Accessing last_called gives unresolved reference error.

Answer (score 3):

```
last_called = None
```

The object named `last_called` is immutable. To change the content of the
object will release the object and assign a new object.

```
print(last_called)
```

Looks like debugging code. `last_called` is seen as the immutable object which
has not been declared as a nonlocal name yet.

```
# nonlocal last_called
```

Even if you uncommented this line, it is after the access of `lasted_call`
by the use of the previous `print`. This is too late to change the scope.

```
last_called = now
```

This is assignment. The `print(last_called)` references `None` in a
different scope and the object is immutable and now attempt to assign a value to it.

The `elapsed` function wants to access the immutable object named `last_called`.
The interpreter progresses to the assignment and cannot continue.
Exception is raised.

Possible options for the behavior of `last_called` within `elapsed`:

1. If `nonlocal last_called` is used, then declare before access and assignment.
2. if `nonlocal last_called` is not declared, then access before assignment causes
   an exception.
3. if `nonlocal last_called` is not declared, access after assignment uses
   a local name `last_called`.

Your code order may work better as:

```
import time
def make_timer():
    last_called = None
    def elapsed():
        now = time.time()
        nonlocal last_called             # declare scope
        print(last_called)               # access
        if last_called is None:          # access
            last_called = now            # assign
        return None
        elapsed_time = now - last_called # access
        last_called = now                # assign
        return elapsed_time
    return elapsed
```

`nonlocal last_called` is uncommented as it is required for option 1.

Answer (score 1):

The error arises because of the assignments to `last_called` inside the `elapsed` function. A variable that isn't declared as `global` or `nonlocal` and gets assigned a value inside the function is a local variable. At the point you're accessing the variable it hasn't been assigned a value yet which causes the error.

```
import time
def make_timer():
    last_called = None
    def elapsed():
        now = time.time()
        print(last_called)
        if last_called is None:
            last_called = now # <- 
            return None
        elapsed_time = now - last_called
        last_called = now # <- 
        return elapsed_time
    return elapsed
```

More info can be found here:
[Why can functions in Python print variables in enclosing scope but cannot use them in assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864041/why-can-functions-in-python-print-variables-in-enclosing-scope-but-cannot-use-th)